# In postgresql, which part of locale causes problems with LIKE operations?

Tags: postgresql, locale, database-performance

There's a lot of discussion around the net about locale other than C or POSIX causing performance problems in postgresql.  I'm not clear though as to which part(s) of the locale setting cause problems and why.

In the manpage for initdb(1), we see:

```
--locale=locale
 Sets the default locale for the database cluster. If this option is not specified, the locale is inherited from the environment that
 initdb runs in. Locale support is described in Section 22.1, \u201cLocale Support\u201d, in the documentation.

--lc-collate=locale, --lc-ctype=locale, --lc-messages=locale, --lc-monetary=locale, --lc-numeric=locale, --lc-time=locale
  Like --locale, but only sets the locale in the specified category.
```

We also see:

```
   To alter the default collation order or character set classes, use the --lc-collate and --lc-ctype options. Collation orders other than C or
   POSIX also have a performance penalty. For these reasons it is important to choose the right locale when running initdb.
```

Does this mean that I could use `--lc-collate POSIX --lc-ctype UTF-8` and avoid performance penalties?  Or are there other performance issues involved?

I'm not surprised that collation affects sort performance, but is that the same issue that arises with LIKE comparisons not using indexes?  Can someone explain what the issue is with the LIKE operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the `text_pattern_ops` operator class and its application for databases that are in locales other than `C`.

The issue is not one of encoding, but of collation.

A b-tree index requires that everything have a single, stable sort order following some invariants, like the assumption that if `a < b` then `b > a`. Comparison operators are used to sort the tree when building and maintaining and index.

For text strings, the collation rules for the language get applied by the comparison operators when determining whether one string is greater than or less than another so that strings sort "correctly" as far as the user is concerned. These rules are locale-dependent, and can do things like ignore punctuation and whitespace.

The `LIKE` operator isn't interested in locales. It just wants to find a prefix string, and it can't just ignore punctuation. So it cannot use a b-tree index that was created with a collation that might ignore punctuation/whitespace, etc. `LIKE` walks down the index tree character by character to find a match, and it can't do that if the index might ignore characters.

That's why, if your DB uses a locale other than "C" (POSIX) you must create different indexes for use with `LIKE`.

Example of localised sorting, compare:

```
regress=> WITH x(v) AS (VALUES ('10'),('1'),('1.'),('2.'),('.2'),('.1'),('1-1'),('11')
)
SELECT v FROM x ORDER BY v COLLATE "en_AU";
  v  
-----
 1
 .1
 1.
 10
 11
 1-1
 .2
 2.
(8 rows)

regress=> WITH x(v) AS (VALUES ('10'),('1'),('1.'),('2.'),('.2'),('.1'),('1-1'),('11')
)
SELECT v FROM x ORDER BY v COLLATE "C";
  v  
-----
 .1
 .2
 1
 1-1
 1.
 10
 11
 2.
(8 rows)
```

The `text_pattern_ops` opclass serves this need. In newer PostgreSQL releases you can create an index with `COLLATE "C"` on the target column instead, serving the same need, e.g.:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_c ON t2(x COLLATE "C");
```

`LIKE` will use such an index, and it can also be used for faster sorting where you don't care about locale for a given operation, e.g.

```
SELECT x FROM t2 ORDER BY x COLLATE "C";
```